# How to get AJAX response every N seconds

Tags: jquery

I want to request this AJAX response every 10 seconds for the results

```
function show() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("ping");
    if (ele.style.display == "none") {
        ele.style.display = "block";
    }
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "checkit.php",
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {
            if (response == 1) {
                alert("Success");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Well for starters its not executing more then once (unless your calling the show() function every 10 seconds) ?

Comment: Your mistake is that you are not calling the show method every 10 seconds. What have you tried for that? I would suggest to check out [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval)

Comment: can you edit the code because I tried the interval

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need a timed loop.

```
function show() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("ping");
    if (ele.style.display == "none") {
        ele.style.display = "block";
    }

    window.setInterval(function(){ //loop

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "checkit.php",
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {
                if (response == 1) {
                    alert("Success");
                }
            }
        });

    }, 10000); //10000 = 10 seconds

}
```

Comment: the user has this tagged as **jQuery**, all but the ajax call is hardcoded **javascript**. This will not help him learn **jQuery**. You need to point this out in your answer.

Comment: It works fine, make sure you are running the function "SHOW()" and that the url: "checkit.php" is correct. Use google Chrome and CTRL+SHIFT+J for console. Also http://jsfiddle.net/SgCrS/5/